# Point root domain to google cloud bucket

Tags: dns, google-cloud-platform, cname

I'm asking this question again as there still doesn't seem to be an elegant solution.

I've bought a domain from https://domains.google.com and I would like to point it to a bucket that I have my static site hosted on. My bucket name is `www.test-domain.dev`, and my domain is `test-domain.dev`.

Using Google Domains DNS I've created a CNAME record name of `www` which is pointing to `c.storage.googleapis.com.`

I've trawled lots of similar issues on here, but no concrete answer...

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to use your own domain/certificate this way. 
Google Cloud Storage static website fronted is [only recommended for HTTP](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website) content. It is possible to use HTTPS but only with standard URI `c.storage.googleapis.com.` This is the reason why you're getting an untrusted certificate warning (`looop.dev` certificate with `storage.googleapis.com` domain).

The way to go is to use an HTTPS load balancer in GCP or a third party CDN in front of your GCS bucket. for more information refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/troubleshooting#https)

To set up an HTTPS load balancer certificate resource see this [link](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates#create-managed-ssl-cert-resource). AKA SSL Offloading.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that's not what I am asking. That has helped though, as ultimately I do need SSL